Симлинк в %SystemRoot% Windows
Помогите пожалуйста с симлинком.
Делаю NO INSTALL для VST плагина.
Примеры - https://rutracker.org/forum/tracker.php?f=1027&nm=symlink
Руководство - https://rutracker.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6092906
Все ссылки получаются рабочие в батнике, но есть проблема с созданием символической ссылки в папку %SystemRoot%
Код:
cmd /c mkdir "%SystemRoot%\system32\"
cmd /c mklink /j "%SystemRoot%\system32\" "%~dp0C\Windows\system32\"

cmd /c mkdir "c:\Windows\SysWOW64\"
cmd /c mklink /j "c:\Windows\SysWOW64\" "%~dp0C\Windows\SysWOW64\"

Ничего в папке %SystemRoot% не создаётся. Пробовал заменять /j на /D - не помогает. Пытался делать ссылки на каждый файл отдельно по принципу:
Код:
cmd /c mklink "c:\Windows\SysWOW64\bmidilib.dll" "%~dp0C\Windows\SysWOW64\bmidilib.dll"

Симлинки создаются, но файлы имеют объем 0 байт и ничего не работает. Не могу понять, где я лажаю.
Помогите решить проблему, пожалуйста.

Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO! как задать хороший вопрос => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask // 1. Если есть конкретные сообщения об ошибках при выполнении команд, их следует указать 2. Приведите минимальный и самодостаточный пример кода, который воспроизводит проблему https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example 3. Укажите, какую версию Windows вы используете и какие права у вас есть

Во что раскрывается данное выражение? %~dp0C\Windows\SysWOW64\
